# Stored procedure which has four input parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a stored procedure which has 4 input parameters.

```
@Scenario, @StockID, @EOD, @EOD_PREV.
```

Based on the @Scenario *(total 9 Scenarios)*, different SQL scripts are executed.

**My requirement is:** 
I need to use VB Macros to display results in each worksheet, I need to  use one ActiveX-Command button to run all the Scenarios. 
Each Scenario in a separate Worksheet.

So far, I have managed to create individual connections for each sheet and Active X Command Button for each sheet.

Below is the query that I used.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Scenario As String   
Dim STOCK_ID As String    
Dim EOD As String    
Dim EOD_PREV As String    
Scenario = Sheets("Stocks").Range("B3").Value    
STOCK_ID = Sheets("Stocks").Range("B8").Value       
EOD = Sheets("Stocks").Range("B6").Value      
EOD_PREV = Sheets("Stocks").Range("B7").Value    
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("9").OLEDBConnection    
.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.usp_Inventory_Reconcilliation '" & Scenario & "','" & 
STOCK_ID & "', '" & EOD & "' ,'" & EOD_PREV & "'"    
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll    
End With    
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me out with this situation.

Comment: I don't really get what is your problem... Do you want to gather all of your refresh in one button? Get the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` out of the `With`, and maybe it'll be easier to use connections without VBA and just use it for your refresh button.

Comment: Thanks R3uK, I called Stored Proc using connections without VBA. Made my life easier. thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm... What is Stored Proc? I'm adding my advice as answer so that you validate it to close the subject if you problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` out of the `With`, and maybe it'll be easier to use connections without VBA and just use it for your refresh button.